# Reading local MDB(Access) database using silverlight 5?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, com

I am tring to find someway to read from local MDB file. It is a requirement that user may have their own access database. And my silverlight app would be interacting and performing calculations on that data. 
Is there any way I can work with it? I have found that ADO.net doesn't come with Silverlight 5. 
All the examples I have seen so far, are assuming that there is Wcf service between silverlight client and database.

Comment: Seilverlight apps are deployed via a web browser. When you say 'It is a requirement that user may have their own access database', where is the mdb file for each user going to reside?

Comment: It would be residing on their own machine. They would be using my app to perform some calculations.

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think is going to be possible. It's certainly not what Silverlight is designed for. Remember Silverlight is a web-browser plug-in - fundamentally it's about providing a richer UI than HTML/Javascript for web pages. Storing databases locally is not something browsers generally support. If you can get it working it's probably not going to work on all platforms (remember Silverlight runs on different browsers and OS platforms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options for you:

1) Using the open file dialog get the user to select the file so you can copy it to the Isolated Storage then work on it and get the user to save the file to disk once you have done.

2) Get the user to install you Silverlight application out of brower, this will give you access to the file system and freedom to read the MDB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(VS.96).aspx#special_features_for_outofbrowser_applications

Personally i prefer the second option.

I'm assuming you are using ADO.Net to read the database, so you'll need to ensure that the correct provided is installed.

good luck

Comment: Sounds like a nice solution. But curious as to why you would use Silverlight for this solution? Given that you are effectively not using Silverlight's two key attributes (browser based deployment, cross-platform support), wouldn't a simple WPF or WinForms app be a better choice?